# $ do jQuery não funciona

Tags: jquery

Estou usando um código que usa **$** do jQuery, só que ao usar o cifrão ele da erro no console e o código jQuery acaba não funcionando. A única solução foi usar **jQuery** ao invés de **$** :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery("#finalizarcadastrojovem").click(function(){

        var form = jQuery("#nome").val();

        console.log(form);

        return false;

    })
})
```

Gostaria de saber como arrumar isso, pois quero usar **$** e não **jQuery**

Comment: Esta usando outro framework que usa o $ também? As vezes por questão de ordem e compatibilidade, o $ acaba sendo sobreescrito, para isso tem a função $.noConflict.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Voce deve ter algum outro script forçando o jQuery ao invés do $

procure por jQuery.noConflict()

mas para te ajudar tente:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#finalizarcadastrojovem").click(function(){

            var form = jQuery("#nome").val();

            console.log(form);

            return false;

        })
    });
</script>
```

Mas o aconselhavél é que você procure nos scripts e tente achar essa forçada de jQuery, caso não tenha nada não sei o que dizer, eu utilizo bastanteo jQuery.noConflict(), de uma olhada http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

Comment: `var $ = jQuery.noConflict();` vai apagar a referência de `$` se outra biblioteca já o estiver a usar e forçar jQuery (!). A probabilidade de gerar novo erro é grande.

Answer (score 5):

O Wakim tem razão, provavelmente há outro código (provavelmente outro framework) usando `$`. Mas o que você talvez não saiba é que o jQuery passa o próprio objeto `jQuery` como argumento do *callback* do `ready`. Portanto você pode fazer assim:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){    
    $("#finalizarcadastrojovem").click(function(){
        var form = $("#nome").val();   
        console.log(form);    
        return false;   
    });
});
```

Comment: Ainda assim, vale a pena verificar os outros frameworks que utiliza e utilizar o `$.noConflict()` para não correr o risco de atrapalhar o outro framework.

Comment: Na verdade tenho quase certeza que o jQuery também define o objeto `jQuery` globalmente e o `$` como atalho. Como ele deve carregar outro framework que sobreescreve o `$`, logo só sobra o `jQuery`.

Comment: Exatamente, @Wakim. E usar o `noConflit` para definir `$` iria interferir com o outro framework. Por isso acho razoável a solução que estou propondo.

Comment: @bfavaretto, o `noConflict` não define o `$`, dê uma olhada: "If you need to use another JavaScript library alongside jQuery, return control of $ back to the other library with a call to $.noConflict()" http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

Comment: @PedroLorentz Isso se o jQuery for carregado depois. No código da pergunta, acredito que ele esteja sendo carregado antes do outro framework.

Answer (score 1):

#### Existem várias maneiras de restaurar o dolar.

Alguns CMS como o wordpress usam por defeito `jQuery` em vez de `$` para evitar possiveis conflitos com outras bibliotecas. Tenha em mente que usar `jQuery` é mais seguro que `$`.

### Para forçar globalmente pode fazer:

```
window.$ = jQuery;
```

Atênção que desta maneira remove o `$` a outras bibliotecas que o possam estar a usar e força o jQuery. Isso vai fazer com que a outra biblioteca dê erro. Manter o `jQuery` é mais seguro.

### Para o fazer "controladamente"

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        jQuery("#finalizarcadastrojovem").click(function () {
            var form = jQuery("#nome").val();
            console.log(form);
            return false;
        })
});
```

Assim pode recuperar o dolar somente dentro deste escopo e no espaço global o dolar está "disponivel" para ser usado por outras bibliotecas.